# Error while Update Status on Timeline

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

```
ERROR :- {"error":{"message":"(200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

I Used the following Code in my application. In this Code if I Open my Facebook account then it is Successfully Post but if other person is logged in then it can't post on his wall.

```
public void postMessageOnWall(String msg) throws FacebookError, JSONException
{
    if (facebook.isSessionValid())
    {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", msg);
        try
        {
            //JSONObject response=Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST"));
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,"POST");
            System.out.println(response);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

I used the FACEBOOK_PERMISSION = "publish_stream" while sharing on facebook.

Comment: What permission do you ask for the users? If the code works for you and not for other people, then it seems like the code asked for some kind of permission for you and some other types of permission for other users!